# Spark Memory issue

Tags: scala

Hi I am very new to Spark.I am trying to execute the following command on Apache Spark scala command line

```
        scala> val files=sc.textFile("/home/test/u.item")
               14/12/06 09:57:40 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(165239) called with 
               curMem=0, maxMem=278302556
               14/12/06 09:57:40 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in 
               memory (estimated size 161.4 KB, free 265.3 MB)
               files: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /home/test/u.item MappedRDD[1] at
               textFile at :12
```

May I please know the steps to correct the above error

Comment: Can you try with a different file (e.g., README.md or any other smaller text file.

Comment: I tried with a really small file and it still didn't work.

Comment: This may be a silly question but are you sure there is any error? I don't see any obvious error message

Comment: Oh the joys of being a newbie.It works gloriously.I don't know what the memory message is about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error message. log4j is logging it as an INFO message (see below the INFO string, between the 2 stars). If it was an error, it would have ERROR level (WARN for warnings). Your output is expected when you invoke the **textFile** method of the context. If you want to log only warnings and errors, I suggest you to change the  level in **log4j.properties** to WARN.

```
14/12/06 09:57:40 **INFO** MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(165239) called with 
           curMem=0, maxMem=278302556
14/12/06 09:57:40 **INFO** MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in 
           memory (estimated size 161.4 KB, free 265.3 MB)
```

I'm not an expert in Spark, but I guess that ensureFreeSpace is a function invoked by MemoryStore to retrieve memory for the Spark Context's activity.

Answer (score 0):

As MiguelPeralvo said, the level in `log4j.properties` can be changed to `WARN`.  To do this, go to the `conf` folder in the spark directory.  If `log4j.properties` doesn't exist, make it from the template in that dir.

```
cp log4j.properties.template log4j.properties
```

then open `log4j.properties` in an editor and change the first line to

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
```

restart spark and the INFO messages should be gone.